# What is the difference between NSURLRequest's mainDocumentURL and URL properties?

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, nsurlrequest, uiwebviewdelegate

I've built a web browser for iOS and I'm trying to pull the URL to display in an address bar.
I look at the `NSURLRequest` in the `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` and the `webViewDidFinishLoad:` `UIWebView` delegate methods.

Should I use the `URL` or the `mainDocumentURL` property of the `NSURLRequest` for that purpose, and what is the difference?

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `URL`.

`mainDocumentURL` would be used when loading sub-parts of a page (like images, scripts, whatever) to tell the system which cookies it can safely use when loading those sub-parts. It’s nothing you’d want to display, and is documented to be unused in the current version of the framework anyhow.

```
/*!
    @method mainDocumentURL
    @abstract The main document URL associated with this load.
    @discussion This URL is used for the cookie "same domain as main
    document" policy. There may also be other future uses.
    See setMainDocumentURL:
    NOTE: In the current implementation, this value is unused by the
    framework. A fully functional version of this method will be available 
    in the future. 
    @result The main document URL.
*/
```

Comment: Where does the documentation say that it is unused? It looks like in the tests I've run that URL is not set and mainDocumentURL is set in the webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: delegate method in some instances.

Comment: I’m not clear how an NSURLRequest would load anything if it doesn’t have a URL to load, but I’m not an expert in this realm.

Comment: I would advise using mainDocumentURL instead of URL. As a matter of fact URL can refer to a sub-part of the site the UIWebView is currently displaying.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is not very clear, but it appears that mainDocumentURL used for cookie policy internals.

From [NSHTTPCookieStorage Class Reference > setCookies:forURL:mainDocumentURL:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSHTTPCookieStorage/setCookies:forURL:mainDocumentURL:)

> mainDocumentURL
>
> The URL of the main HTML document for the top-level frame, if known. Can be nil. This URL is used to determine if the cookie should be accepted if the cookie accept policy is NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyOnlyFromMainDocumentDomain.

If it's possible that the URL you are using is a sub-frame or some media type embedded in an HTML document, then you may wish to know what the mainDocumentURL is; otherwise, just use URL.